# Configure a threadpool for scheduling tasks and their cancellations also

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, java-threads

In our current service architecture, we have a single scheduled threadpool, that is used for executing some computation tasks (for real-time data gathering). These tasks are time-bound, so in case they don't complete in a set amount of time, they are interrupted by scheduling cancellation tasks, which are submitted along with the original tasks. The issue we're seeing is that the cancellations are not always on time, and that some of the tasks can take longer to be cancelled than expected.

According to me, this could be because we are using a common threadpool, where sometimes the cancellation tasks are not getting picked up on time. But I'm not sure about this. Is there a way to confirm this, or find the actual cause of the delays in cancellations?

Comment: IIUC, you can cancel the tasks using the scheduler, but you need to implement the actual cancellation in the task yourself by peridocially checking `isCancelled`.

Comment: yes, it all depends on how your tasks react to the interruption

Answer (score 0):

*- they are interrupted by scheduling cancellation tasks*

you have scheduled a task to interrupt the original on a scheduled threadpool ?

If so, I think the scheduled thread pool guarantees to wait at *least* for the  delay period. Ie there is no guarantee it will run after precisely the delay period.